# SQL Return rows based on value of other rows

Tags: sql, select, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

We use a database to capture transactions / deals and I need to find out which one is the most up-to-date deal.

- When a new transaction is put in, the database column `Action` is set to "Insert" and the column `Modified` is set to "No".
- If an update happens, 2 additional rows are written `Action` = "Delete"; `Modified` = "Yes" AND `Action` = "Insert"; `Modified` = "Yes".
- If a transaction gets deleted another row is added: `Action` = "Delete"; `Modified` = "No"

Here are some examples:

- Deal A was only inserted. Therefore, I need to return `Record` 1.
- Deal B was inserted and updated. I would need the query to return `Record` 4.
- Deal C was inserted and deleted. The query should not return deal C at all.
- Deal D was inserted and updated twice. I need `Record` 11 to be returned.
- Deal E was inserted, updated twice and then deleted. The query should not return deal E at all.

[image: Sample Deals]

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* I followed you correctly, you can filter on the latest record per deal with a subquery, and then ignore deals whose last status is a deletion:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    t.record = (select max(t1.record) from mytable t1 where t1.dealID = t.dealID)
    and t.action <> 'Delete'
```

As far as concerns, you don't need to use column `modified` to get the result that you want.

For performance with this query, consider an index on `(dealID, record, action)`.

You can also express this with `row_number()`, if your database supports window functions:

```
select record, action, modified, dealID
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by dealID order by record desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where action <> 'Deleted'
```

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect. I was trying to figure it out with EXISTS but this is very elegant. How would you have solved it if the Delete was not always at the end in an update?